# How to sum hours in Tfs?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am required to put in a certain number of hours into TFS for my work items daily.

Currently, I have the following query which shows all the items I worked on during the day:

[image]

Is it possible to aggregate all the hours worked TODAY on all tasks. For example, if you go to the ALL CHANGES section of a specific item, you will see details on hours:

[image]

**Is it possible to aggregate all the hours worked TODAY on all tasks?.**

Comment: Another words you're not familiar with any of the tags? How did you stumble upon this?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' eh good point, I removed that comment. I'll check back later to see what the answer is and if it contains c# code or not.

Comment: There is a way to visually show it by creating a query that has all your PBIs then create a chart by summing the number of hours logged.

Comment: @BalázsKámán yes that is the very problem, i'm not sure what criteria i would use to create that query

Comment: @Quantic what were your findings? it's been almost 4 years

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' I still don't see any `c#` tag relevance. The tag could have 1,385,510 questions instead of 1,385,511  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Feel free to delete the question @quantic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make a chart, and select SUM from values section.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

ALL CHANGES section is the history of a single work item. There is not a default way to sum the completed work column in TFS. As an alternative, you can export the query to Excel, and sum the completed work column in Excel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. One is simpler than the other. As Cece pointed out you can export your query to excel and do the math with excel. In visual studio you can right click on the query and say export to excel. I'm not sure off the top of my head if you can do it in the web interface been awhile since i worked with it. There is another programmatic way to do it but you need access to edit work items as well as installing 3rd party software on the server your TFS instance is installed. Although if you are using the Microsoft hosted version you might be able to install an extension to do this.